# Nextjs - Input hydration error when using type email

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's an odd one, does anyone know why I'd get a hydration error when using a type of email on an input? This only seems to happen in firefox as well?

```
const Input = ({ type = 'text' }) => {
  return <input type={type} />
}

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Input type="email" />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

Other types such as password don't return the error, just email?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. See https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-haslett-um0jht (open in Firefox). Are you certain the hydration error comes from that code?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in Next.js; I've reported it here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44644

Edit: looks like the issue is a browser extension adding something to email input fields, like [Firefox Relay](https://relay.firefox.com/) or [DDG Privacy Essentials](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-for-firefox/). Uninstall those or [disable the icon](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-enable-disable-firefox-relay-icon-on-online-fields-and-websites) to fix this.